# php cross-domain error - need to replace string?

Tags: php, cross-domain

I'm using a php script to pass json data from another domain to my javascript file.  My code works fine for most responses. However, in a few cases there are much longer values with lines broken by "\r\n\r\n", and in those cases I get an error when I try to parse the results.  I think maybe the "\r\n\r\n" is causing the error, and was hoping to replace that string with a space in my php script before passing it on to my javascript, but I'm not sure how - I'm a newbie.

php script:

> echo "var forecast='";  
>   include('http://ws1.airnowgateway.org/GatewayWebServiceREST/Gateway.svc/forecastbyzipcode?zipcode=' . $zipcode . '&format=json&key=[myKey]'); 
>   echo "';";

javascript code:

> $(document).ready(function() { 
>     $.get(url, function(data) { 
>     myData = JSON.parse(forecast); 
>   ... etc.

I was hoping I could use str_replace within that php script, but I know I've set this up wrong, because it's replacing within the url itself, not the response data:

> echo "var forecast='"; 
>   include(str_replace("\r\n"," ","http://ws1.airnowgateway.org/GatewayWebServiceREST/Gateway.svc/forecastbyzipcode?zipcode=" . $zipcode . "&format=json&key=[myKey]")); 
>   echo "';";

Am I on the right track?

Comment: include is used to import another php file, from trusted source, like your website's hard disk; if you want to read an url's content, try file_get_contents, or php-curl.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that include simply echos out the result of the call to the url. Try using `file_get_contents`:

```
echo "var forecast='";  
$res = file_get_contents("http://ws1.airnowgateway.org/GatewayWebServiceREST/Gateway.svc/forecastbyzipcode?zipcode=" . $zipcode . "&format=json&key=[myKey]");
echo str_replace("\r\n",$res); 
echo "';";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should **never** use `include` to grab external URLs for use in your app. You don't control the output, so you cannot predict how the script will behave.

---

That said, instead of using `include`, consider using `curl` or `file_get_contents`.

Looking at a similar question, I see that that API supports `JSONP`. This does exactly what you want without you having to build a server-side relay at all.

Try adding a `callback` parameter to the request URL. You can call it from your javascript code in your originating page, and it will run the function specified by the `callback` value.